# Laptop battery completely discharges while in the laptop, even when not in use

Tags: laptop, battery

My Laptop Battery completely discharges while in the laptop, even when not in use.

I fully charged the battery, removed it from the laptop, and kept it separate. After 3 days I checked it and it was 97%.

But if I leave it in my laptop, the battery completely dies (0%) within 02 days, even after proper shutdown and no usage. For this problem, I have tried formatting it and re-installed windows but of no use, problem not resolved.

That means my battery only discharge when it is inserted in the laptop.

Please help, what should I do / check?

Comment: Sounds like you should replace the battery.  The battery should still have a charge after 2 days, but its normal, for a battery to lose its charge if its just sitting on the shelf.

Comment: Have you run any diagnostics specific to your model laptop? There may be a hardware issue causing the laptop to drain the battery. **BUT** if the battery is more than a couple years old, it may likely need to be replaced.

Comment: Are you sure your laptop is not waking up?

Comment: @Ramhound the thing is OP's battery doesn't discharge that fast on the shelf, but it does when in the laptop.

Comment: Thanks all for your support & reply, @CharlieRB -  tried HP Uefi diagnosis & HP adviser - all the test were ok,       @ Ramhound- my point is, when i leave battery in laptop discharges repeatedly, within 48 Hrs, but when i leave it outside a nominal/acceptable amount is discharges, to over cover the problem i have again formatted my laptop & installed win 7 32bit (in case if it is any windows setting issue) BIOS is set to default, & updated with latest version

Comment: Could this be "sleep" versus "hibernate"? If I put my laptop to sleep, it will discharge in a few days. Hibernate (or complete shutdown) it will not. Sometimes when sleeping you can see a blinking light. With hibernate or complete shutdown there are no lights at all.